# JAXB - XSD validation on unmarshal do not fail on missing attribute

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd, xsd-validation

I have a problem with the unmarshal method and the validation of anattribute. I have an attribute that is set as "fixed" in my XSD and when I tried to unmarshal a XML which does not contain this fixed attribute, no error is raised. For me, the XML is not valid because the attribute is not present and should raise an exception.

Here is my XSD :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="toto">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="bigelement">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="oneelement" type="xs:boolean"/>
              <xs:element name="anotherelement" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" fixed="myname"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is my XML I try to unmarshal :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<toto>
    <bigelement>
        <oneelement>true</oneelement>
        <anotherelement>hello</anotherelement>
    </bigelement>
</toto>
```

And here is my method that unmarshal:

```
    try
    {
      JAXBContext context =JAXBContext.newInstance("com.test");
      Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
      Object o = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(message));
      Toto command = (Toto)o;
      return command;
    }
    catch (JAXBException e)
    {
      return null;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
      return null;
    }
```

As you can see, in my XML I didn't set the attribute "name", **so I expect that my unmarshaller.unmarshal raises an exception that the XML is not valid** but it builds the Java Object correctly without any error.

I tried to add a ValidationEventHandler with a validation with the Schema XSD but no error is raised.

What am I doing wrong in my code? Is it the fact that the attribute is set as "fixed" into the XSD that no error is raised?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, I read more carefully the w3schools about attributes and I found that :

> Attributes are optional by default. To specify that the attribute is
>   required, use the "use" attribute:
>
> ```
> <xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
> ```

I always thought attributes were required.

Very sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the help and the link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the XML schema as an instance of [`javax.xml.validation.Schema`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Schema.html) on the `Unmarshaller` to enable validation.

```java
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("toto.xsd")); 
    unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about this on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I already tried that but I will try again (maybe I missed something).
I will come back to let you know if I succeed.